# com.google.android.exoplayer2.c0: java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: android, video, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

the Video Widget is ExoPlayer

there is an error when i play the video

url: https://cdn-app-test.jiaoyoushow.com/app/vv/video/110011041/110011041_8be6c4be-ebc7-4ca4-87e7-83d053432c5d.mp4

Exception:

```
2021-03-13 16:41:55.461 15181-16016/com.shenqi.app.wasai E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Renderer error: index=0, type=video, format=Format(2, null, null, video/avc, null, -1, null, [72, 640, 53.627686], [-1, -1]), rendererSupport=YES
      com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: java.lang.IllegalStateExceptio
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.BaseRenderer.createRendererException(BaseRenderer.java:359)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.render(MediaCodecRenderer.java:735)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:599)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:329)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at android.media.MediaCodec.native_dequeueOutputBuffer(Native Method)
        at android.media.MediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(MediaCodec.java:2789)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.drainOutputBuffer(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1520)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.render(MediaCodecRenderer.java:721)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:599) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:329) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224) 
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67) 
2021-03-13 16:41:55.462 15181-16016/com.shenqi.app.wasai E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Disable failed.
      java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at android.media.MediaCodec.native_flush(Native Method)
        at android.media.MediaCodec.flush(MediaCodec.java:2194)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.flushOrReleaseCodec(MediaCodecRenderer.java:777)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.MediaCodecVideoRenderer.flushOrReleaseCodec(MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java:724)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.onDisabled(MediaCodecRenderer.java:636)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.MediaCodecVideoRenderer.onDisabled(MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java:569)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.BaseRenderer.disable(BaseRenderer.java:168)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.disableRenderer(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:1136)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.resetInternal(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:891)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.stopInternal(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:850)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:382)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
2021-03-13 16:41:55.465 15181-15997/com.shenqi.app.wasai E/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-0-15181-2] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has no connected producer
2021-03-13 16:41:55.467 15181-16016/com.shenqi.app.wasai E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Reset failed.
      java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at android.media.MediaCodec.native_stop(Native Method)
        at android.media.MediaCodec.stop(MediaCodec.java:2147)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.releaseCodec(MediaCodecRenderer.java:671)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.MediaCodecVideoRenderer.releaseCodec(MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java:714)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.onReset(MediaCodecRenderer.java:643)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.MediaCodecVideoRenderer.onReset(MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java:578)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.BaseRenderer.reset(BaseRenderer.java:175)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.resetInternal(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:900)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.stopInternal(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:850)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:382)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```

Video is normal and i don't know what to do